# How to break out of Unity? Jail a user to a program

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kiosk, ubuntu-unity

I am trying to setup a media center that I also want to be able to use for some other stuff. My idea was that I would just make it so that when the Media Center user logs in it just launches a program not a full desktop environment, and if that program closes it logs out the user. I have tried `~/.xsession` as well as some other stuff even got desperate and set the shell in passwd to the desired program to no avail.

The reason I wanted to do this is that my roommate is almost 100% inept at anything computer related, and if I don't lock it down I feel she will find a way to break something in it. Also the user will have a very easy/weak password, so I would like to lock it down as much as possible.

Comment: Would it be OK to lock down the user to only the media center application? You could do this by making Ubuntu into a kiosk like [Oli](http://superuser.com/users/30127/oli) explained how to do in his blog, ThePCSpy. If this isn't OK, please comment and I'll remove the kiosk tag or edit your own question and remove it yourself.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I want but just to confirm that would still allow me to login with my own user and get a full desktop right? Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: I told Oli about your question.

Comment: Thank you I reviewed both of his blog posts and they don't quite work because they do not allow me to have the main login it has to replace it I believe. They are so very close though!